# In Single Activity Architecture, If I start an activity multiple times from any of my fragment, my app is becoming slow

Tags: java, android, performance, kotlin

I've an activity in which I've almost 20 fragments. App is working perfectly fine but :

1. When I opens any activity (either implicit or explicit) from a fragment and press back, my app is gradually becoming slow (UI is lagging mostly on scrolling).

Sluggish behavior of the app increases on the basis of repeating the step 1 again & again

While doing RCA, I was thinking that this might be happening because of some specific heavy activity or fragment so, I've created a sample activity which I've tried opening from different fragments but the issue is still there and it is not related to a specific activity or fragment it is related to all over the app

Need an expert opinion how to resolved this issue

Tried multiple things :

- Removed unused resources
- Used coroutines for heavy tasks
- Network cache api
- Profiler is not showing anything wired
  etc etc..

Also, I'd like to mention an amazing thing happened to me :
My app is live on playstore since an year ago and it was working perfectly fine!

Almost a month ago, suddenly, the app has started this sluggish behavior without publishing any update on playstore

**Fix :**

- Resolved this issue by just making this boolean "false"

  ```
  <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoInitEnabled"
           android:value="false"/>
  ```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: `When I opens any activity` Any? You said you had only one activity. Dont understand.

Comment: Yes, I've single activity but I'm trying to share an image from one of my fragment and for that I need to start an activity

Comment: Which activity? Your activity is already running. Your fragment is in an activity that runs. Still don't understand.

Comment: Yes, my activity is already running and my fragments are within this activity and as per the requirement I'm trying to open another activity from one of my fragment

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on `StrictMode` and add `LeakCanary` to evaluate the most obvious issues with your performance.

After that try to to turn on Proguard to obfuscate and strip code from not relevant things.

If performance still will be an issue, consider to move code into separate activities or to try `compose` if you have specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.
Let me try this and will get back to you

Comment: I've integrated leak canary and it's not showing any critical voilations which can impact this sluggish behavior of my app

Comment: I've also turned on the proguard to obfuscate but the issue is still there

Comment: I cannot move my code to separate activities its a production code and my app is already live.
Unable to do these big updates

Comment: Then I would go with more low level profiling tools. In the past there was ```MAT```, but nowadays it is integrated within a studio. Please take a look specific android official docs about memory profiling (https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/) - you have to figure out where is the most memory is consumed which will give you a clue where are possible problems might be. Also take a look on method tracing ```Debug.startMethodTracing()``` to further narrow down your bottle necks in performance.